# Use for-of to assign to the elements of an array

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to use a for-of loop to assign to elements of an iterable? Something like this, where it actually will change the values of the elements in the array.

```
for (let e of some_array) {
    e = new_value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array#entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) to get the array element and the index:

```
for (let [i, e] of some_array.entries()) {
    some_array[i] = new_value;
}
```

But in such a case I would probably just stick with a normal `for` loop or use `Array#map`.